# add foreign key to multiple existing tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, foreign-keys

I have a table 'user' with userid as PK.I need to add this as a FK to 2 columns of multiple existing tables. For now, I am updating each table the foll. way.

```
alter table table1
add foreign key(createdby) references users(id)
go
alter table table1
add foreign key(createdby) references users(id)
go
```

Is there a simpler way to update all tables in one go. Thank you.

Comment: If you are using an application like coldfusion, .net, etc, and those applications have the necessary permisions, you could loop through a list of tablenames.

Comment: Hi. I am using sql server 2008 r2. I can get the tbl names by:"select table_name from information_schema.columns where column_name ='createdby' and table_catalog='dbtables'....but i dont know hw to proceed further

Comment: No, there is no simpler way to do this - if you want to add foreign keys to 10 tables, you need to write 10 `ALTER TABLE` commands.

Comment: The common way to execute automated DDL statements from a query is to declare a cursor then loop over the cursor result and use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE for standard SQL or EXEC() for SQL Server.

Comment: You can add foreign keys in a database diagram in SSMS.  It's just a matter of dragon dropping (?!) from a column in the referencing table to the corresponding column in the defining table.

Comment: People frequently make this mistake. It's almost always a better idea (if you need accountability) to store separate audit rows in a separate table. Otherwise, all the the `modifiedby` column tells you is who *last* updated a row - which may have been a *trivial* update. If you need to know who made a *particular* modification, it's almost always better to have an explicit history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maby something like this would do the trick!

```
DECLARE @TableName AS NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @Schema AS NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @Modify AS INTEGER
DECLARE @Created AS INTEGER
DECLARE @sql1 as nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @sql2 as nvarchar(max)
DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR
SELECT
A.[name],
S.[name] as schemaname,
(SELECT 1 FROM sys.all_objects innero 
where innero.[name] = 'FK_ModifiedBy' 
AND innero.parent_object_id = a.[object_id]) as ModifiedBy,
(SELECT 1 FROM sys.all_objects innero 
where innero.[name] = 'FK_CreatedBy' 
AND innero.parent_object_id = a.[object_id]) as CreatedBy
FROM
    sys.all_objects A
INNER JOIN
sys.all_columns O ON
A.[object_id] = O.[object_id]
INNER JOIN
SYS.schemas S ON
A.[schema_id] = S.[schema_id]
WHERE
O.name = 'ModifiedBy'
OPEN curs
FETCH NEXT FROM curs
INTO @TableName, @Schema, @Modify, @Created
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
IF @Modify IS NULL
BEGIN
set @sql1 = N'ALTER TABLE ' + @Schema + '.' + @TableName 
 + ' ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ModifiedBy FOREIGN KEY (ModifiedBy) 
REFERENCES ' + @Schema + '.Users(userid)'
exec SP_EXECUTESQL @sql1
END
IF @Created IS NULL
BEGIN
set @sql2 = N'ALTER TABLE ' + @Schema + '.' + @TableName 
+ ' ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CreatedBy FOREIGN KEY (createdby) 
REFERENCES ' + @Schema + '.Users(userid)'
exec SP_EXECUTESQL @sql2
END
FETCH NEXT FROM curs
INTO @TableName, @Schema, @Modify, @Created
END
CLOSE curs
DEALLOCATE curs
```

Sorry for not good indenting in the sql build up, seems a little cumbersome to make it good here. This probably need a little tuning when if some tables only has one of the other two columns.

Comment: We all have our own preferences and mine is that the elimination of horizontal scrolling is much more important than indenting.

Answer (score 1):

This is for another database with different syntax and a different DDL change but the structure is the same. Declare a cursor that queries the data dictionary tables and returns the SQL statements you want to run, then open and loop over the cursor while executing each statement.

```
DECLARE SQLStr SHORTSTRING(1000);
DECLARE NoDefaultsCursor CURSOR FOR
   SELECT 'ALTER TABLE "' || TABLE_NAME ||
          '" ALTER COLUMN "' || FIELD_NAME || '" SET DEFAULT ' ||
     CASE FIELD_TYPE_SQL
       WHEN 'INTEGER' THEN '0'
       WHEN 'BOOLEAN' THEN 'FALSE'
       WHEN 'SHORTSTRING' THEN ''''''
       WHEN 'CHARACTER VARYING' THEN ''''''
     END || ';' AS AddDefaultSQL
   FROM #FIELDS WHERE NOT FIELD_HASDEFAULT
     AND FIELD_TYPE_SQL IN
       ('INTEGER','BOOLEAN','SHORTSTRING','CHARACTER VARYING');
OPEN NoDefaultsCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM NoDefaultsCursor INTO SQLStr;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 DO
    Execute Immediate SQLStr;
    FETCH NEXT FROM NoDefaultsCursor INTO SQLStr;
END WHILE;
CLOSE NoDefaultsCursor;
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried a compact version of christer.This worked too. Thought might be of help to someone else

```
declare @tblname nvarchar(50),@sql1 nvarchar(max),@sql2 nvarchar(max)
declare curs cursor for
select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME ='createdby'
open curs
 fetch next from curs into @tblname
 while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
  begin
   set @sql1='alter table dbo.'+ @tblname+
   ' add foreign key(createdby) references users(id)'
   exec sp_executesql @sql1
   set @sql2='alter table dbo.'+@tblname+
   ' add foreign key(modifiedby) references users(id)'
   exec sp_executesql @sql2
   fetch next from curs into @tblname
  end
close curs
deallocate curs
```

Comment: This will work, but you cant run it multible times, belive you will get errors then. Also if you have multible schema's you will have to include that aswell. Good thing it worked for you! :)